# POST METHOD: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do  POST method using fetch, but this error occurs. 'Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.'

```
function ValidateNew(){
var firstNew = document.getElementById("firstNew").checked;
var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
var imageSource = document.getElementById("imageSource").value;
var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
var link = document.getElementById("link").value;

let _data = {
    firstNew: firstNew,
    Title: title,
    Source: imageSource,
    Date: date,
    Description: description,
    Link:link,
}
console.log(_data);

const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(_data)
        };
        const result = await fetch(
            'https://d9qoarugmf.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api/news?key=jpIEEC', requestOptions            );
        setData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
}, []);
```

console.log(data.hits.map(0));
return (

  {data.hits.map(item => (

  {item.title}
  ))}

);
}

Comment: You cannot use a React hook outside a react functional component and your `ValidateNew()` is not a react functional component (it does not return anything, to begin with) but a "normal" javascript function. As a side note, all those `document.getElementById()` should be avoided, as the React way of doing things involves using (very sparingly) React refs.

Comment: Apologies, I just notice your function does return something but that part of the code is outside the code block. Anyway, what you are returning is an array of strings while a React component should return... well, a valid component or an array of valid components. You might want to return something like `<ul>{data.hits.map(item => <li>item.title</li>)}</ul>`